# Regarding the column "How much money are you planning to spend on your visit to the UK?"

Tags: visas, uk

I am an Indian citizen applying for UK standard visitor visa.

For the question "How much money are you planning to spend on
your visit to the UK?" I have said 1,00,000 INR.

I was thinking (and I remember seeing) that they are asking me to include the flight fares, accommodation charges and all.

My institute is providing money to buy tickets, Visa, Registration (for conference) and host instiute is providing accomodation.

Does these two comes under "How much money are **you** planning to spend on your visit to the UK?" or did I conveyed them that I am planning to spend 1.00,000 INR apart from tickets and all that.

Comment: This question may need a canonical response. It's been asked hundred of times here in various forms

Comment: You may want to run a search on all your questions and all others that come up during your planning sessions as there are many people who have done that same planning and there are a lot of answers already.

Comment: @Willeke I searched for 3 hours and got nothing so had to ask here :)